# XAMPP using SQLServer to update table in MSSQL, Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sql-update, sqlsrv

I have this code below to update a table using PHP Driver for SQL Server that's connected to an SQL server. When I run this code, I got connection established, but there's an error in the line `sqlsrv_query`, which I always get Notice:

> Array to String conversion in ....

How do i fix this ?

```
<?php
    // Insert CustomerID, CustomerName,CustomerCountry,SubsID,SubsType
    $CustID=$_POST['cust_id'];
    $CustName=$_POST['cust_name'];
    $CustCountry=$_POST['cust_country'];
    $SubsID=$_POST['cust_subs'];
    $SubsType=$_POST['cust_subsType'];
    $custPhone=$_POST['cust_phone'];
    
    //connect to database
    $serverName = "DESKTOP-DMI3TT9";
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"DB_LaNahFlex_2");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
    
    if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    
    //Query
    $sql="INSERT INTO Customer
        (CustomerID, CustName,CustomerCountry,CustomerPhone)
         VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $var=array('$CustID','$CustName','$CustCountry','$custPhone');
    
    if(sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$var)){
        echo "Success";
        //header('location:0.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "Fail";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$var=array('$CustID','$CustName','$CustCountry','$custPhone');` ... is CustomerID a string (varchar/nvarchar) or a number (int)?

Comment: Replace `$var=array('$CustID','$CustName','$CustCountry','$custPhone')` with `$var=array($CustID,$CustName,$CustCountry,$custPhone)`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, varchar, all the datatype is varchar

Comment: @7drago7 The `sqlsrv_query()` call seems correct (if you use `$var=array($CustID,$CustName,$CustCountry,$custPhone)`. Are you sure about the line, that causes this notice?